# Autonumeration error, CS Error: Numbering ID is null

Tags: acumatica

I create Setup DAC for my numbering atribute and
add Setup view to graph, althouh I insert new numerattor to my setup, but when I create new document,
system show me this error.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIjEc.png)

I try to change the numerator and setup class, and its work, but I used deffaul SO shipment numbering atribut.
So i need use my numerator.

Main Dac field with AutoNumber atribute

```
[PXDBString(15, IsKey = true, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = ">CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC")]
    [PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.NullOrBlank)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Ref. Nbr.", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    [AutoNumber(typeof(ASPaymentCalendarPreferences.revenueForecastNumberingID), typeof(ASRevenueForecast.date))]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search<ASRevenueForecast.reqNbr>))]
    public virtual string ReqNbr { get; set; }
    public abstract class reqNbr : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<reqNbr> { }
```

Setup Dav code:

```
[PXPrimaryGraph(typeof(ASPaymentCalendarPreferencesMaint))]
[PXCacheName("Payment Calendar Preferences")]
public class ASPaymentCalendarPreferences : IBqlTable
{
    #region Keys
    public static class FK
    {
        public class RevenueForecastNumberingID : PX.Objects.CS.Numbering.PK.ForeignKeyOf<ASPaymentCalendarPreferences>.By<revenueForecastNumberingID> { }
    }   
    #endregion

    #region RevenueForecastNumberingID
    public abstract class revenueForecastNumberingID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<revenueForecastNumberingID> { }
    protected String _RevenueForecastNumberingID;
    [PXDBString(10, IsUnicode = true)]
    [PXDefault("REVENUEFO")]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Numbering.numberingID), DescriptionField = typeof(Numbering.descr))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Revenue Forecast Numbering", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible)]
    public virtual String RevenueForecastNumberingID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._RevenueForecastNumberingID;
        }
        set
        {
            this._RevenueForecastNumberingID = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Main Graph constructor:

```
  public PXSetup<ASPaymentCalendarPreferences> AutoNumSetup;
    public PXSetup<PX.Objects.GL.Company> Company;

    #endregion

    #region Graph constructor
    public ASRevenueForecastEntry()
    {
        ASPaymentCalendarPreferences setup = AutoNumSetup.Current;
      
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: The error did not attach

Comment: Add a photo of error

Comment: I apologize, I should have also asked for the code for the attribute that is set to auto number, as well as any other relevant code for the attribute that is set/get.

Comment: Add a code parts

Answer (score 0):

I founded answer. I create db field with char(10) type, but atribute need nvarchach(10) type.